# StatsLib library in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to use the [StatsLib](https://github.com/kthohr/stats) library created by Keith O'Hara in CLion.

I have downloaded all the files from GitHub, but how do I get to use it in my project?

Namely,

1. Where do I save the downloaded files?
2. How do I edit my CMakeLists.txt?
3. What are all the #include that I need and where should they be placed?
4. How can I get a simple example like this to work:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "stats.hpp"

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       // evaluate the normal PDF at x = 1, mu = 0, sigma = 1
       double test = stats::dnorm(1.0,0.0,1.0);
       cout<<test<<endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   EDIT

Following the answer supplied I have copied the unzipped folders containing gcem and stats into my project root. My CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test_project main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_project stats/include gcem/include)
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments
```

Your help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the [Installation and Dependencies](https://github.com/kthohr/stats#installation-and-dependencies) section on the GitHub page?

Comment: `How can I get a simple example like this to work:` - you need to at least add `#include <iostream>` and `using std::cout; using std:;endll`,

Comment: I have read the section you are referring to, however, I am still not clear on the 4 points outlined above.

I have included iostream and namespace std - will also add to the code in the question for clarity,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small project you can get away with just cloning `stats` and `gcem` to separate directories in your project root directory.
In `CMakeLists.txt` it then suffices to add

```
target_include_directories(my_app PUBLIC stats/include gcem/include)
```

To do it properly, you need to make `INTERFACE` or `IMPORTED` library targets out of each so you can link to them. [This tutorial](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) gives a nice overview.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a useful comment. I have now added the two folders gcem and stats into my project root directory and added the line you specified to my CMakeLists.txt. I have changed my_app to the name of my project. I get the following error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments. Any idea why? I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add the `PUBLIC` (or `PRIVATE`) keyword as well. I got confused with `include_directories` which does not need that keyword.

Comment: Could you please also specify where to include it exactly? Apologies, I am completely new to this! Your help is much appreciated.